# Quero fazer um tweet a cada 240char mas não é reconhecido - Python(Tweepy)

Tags: python, txt, caracteres

Quero que o programa leia o .txt, grave os 240char e poste o tweet, e pule para os próximos 240char, como se tivesse lendo e postando cada linha, mas invés de linha séria por quantidade de char. Porém não estou conseguindo identificar como, alguém poderia me ajudar?

**Código:**

```
# reading 
    
    bookfile = open('book.txt', encoding = 'utf8')
    booklines = bookfile.readlines()
    bookfile.close()
    
    
    # tweet
    
    def tweet():
        for line in booklines:
            try:
                 print(line)
                 if line != '\n':
                     api.update_status(line, tweet_mode = 'extended')
                     sleep(300)
                 else:
                    pass
            except tweepy.TweepError as e:
                print(e.reason)
                sleep(2)
    
    tweet()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `textwrap.wrap` que já retornará para você uma lista de substrings com o tamanho definido.

```py
from textwrap import wrap

...
booklines = wrap(bookfile.read(), width=240)

for message in booklines:
  # Envia o tweet
```

Comment: No caso ficaria, certo? ou como?

'''bookfile = open('book.txt', encoding = 'utf8')
booklines = wrap(bookfile.read(240))
bookfile.close()


for message in booklines:'''

Comment: @Patok Adicionei o parâmetro que havia esquecido...